# Adding New Fonts to Tesseract 3

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to add new fonts to tesseract ocr. I'm following [this tutorial](http://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine) but I'm having some problems.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Create training document

   `convert eng.myfont.exp0.pdf eng.myfont.exp0.tif`
2. Train Tesseract

   `tesseract eng.myfont.exp0.tif eng.myfont.exp0 batch.nochop makebox`

   This created my eng.myfont.exp0.box file.

   I open the file with moshpytt and make sure it was detected correctly.
3. Feed the box file back into tesseract

   `tesseract eng.myfont.exp0.tif eng.myfont.exp0.box nobatch box.train.stderr`

   I have this result:

   > Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica
   >   APPLY_BOXES:
   >   Boxes read from boxfile:     146
   >   Found 146 good blobs.
   >   TRAINING ... Font name = myfont.exp0
   >   Generated training data for 6 words

   - eng.myfont.exp0.box.tr file and eng.myfont.exp0.box.txt generated
4. try to detect the Character set used in the box file (this is where I get stuck)

   `unicharset_extractor *.box`

Result:

> unicharset_extractor: command not found

I also tred `unicharset_extractor eng.myfont.exp0.box` with the same result.

I'm using:

- tesseract 3.03
- leptonica-1.70
- libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8 : webp 0.4.0
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: That's pretty peculiar. It just means the command cannot be found. On my system I'm able to find that command without any issue in `/usr/local/bin/unicharset_extractor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The training tools for Tesseract 3.03 RC were omitted from Ubuntu 14.04. So either fall back to Tesseract 3.02 or upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10, which should have it.

Comment: I have also got same issue in OS X EI Captain 10.11.1 terminal. I have using below versions                                                                                    tesseract 3.04.01
 leptonica-1.72
  libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.6.21 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.5

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I googled this for you. Here's the answer:

> You need to run all commands in the same folder where are located your input files.

From:

- https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=945 and
- https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3#Background_and_Limitations