# Tesseract unicharset_extractor command not found

Tags: bash, path, tesseract, osx-elcapitan, image-recognition

**My Problem**

Running `unicharset_extractor` and receiving :

> unicharset_extractor: command not found

**My Environment**

```
OSX El Capitan Version 10.11.4

Terminal Version 2.6.1 (361.1)

tesseract 3.04.00
 leptonica-1.73
  libgif 4.2.3 : libjpeg 9a : libpng 1.6.21 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.5.0 : libopenjp2 2.1.0
```

**Similar Questions**

This question has been asked quite a bit, but non seems to solve my problem. Some of the non-working questions are listed here:

[unicharset_extractor: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304824/unicharset-extractor-command-not-found)

[Adding New Fonts to Tesseract 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205480/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3)

[Issue 1327 in tesseract-ocr: unicharset_extractor statement doesn´t work](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tesseract-issues/TWTL_d3o6Ec/dRhmh3HPGa0J)

**What I'm doing**

I am currently trying to train my [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr) to recognise custom numbers.

**What I've done**

I originally installed `tesseract` using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), which installed `tesseract`, `leptonica`, and other dependencies to `/usr/local/Cellar`. I used [this](http://www.resolveradiologic.com/blog/2013/01/15/training-tesseract/) guide to help me train the data. Like the guide instructed, I first generated a set of `.tif` files in the format of `tla.test_font.exp[num].tif`. Then I generated the `.box` files using this script:

```
for i in `seq 0 52`;
do
    tesseract tla.test_font.exp$i.tif tla.test_font.exp$i -l eng -psm 10 batch.nochop makebox
done
```

Then I ran the `.box` files through tesseract using:

```
for i in `seq 0 52`;
do
    tesseract tla.test_font.exp$i.tif tla.test_font.exp$i -l eng -psm 10 nobatch box.train
done
```

Then I tried to run `unicharset_extractor *.box` and I received the error message above.

Suspecting it has something to do with my `tesseract` install path, and not wanting to mess things even more using symlink, I then uninstalled `tesseract`, `libtool` and `leptonica` from `usr/local/Cellar`, and used [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) to install everything again. This time in `/opt/local/bin`. After repeating the same steps mentioned above, I got stuck on the same issue. I even tried running `man unicharset_extractor` and the man page worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

While installing tesseract you haven't installed the training tools. Now you will have to uninstall tesseract using the following command 
***brew uninstall tesseract***
and then install the tools using 
***brew install --with-training-tools tesseract***

After this you should be able to run unicharset_extractor command.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answering this after so long. I no longer have the correct environment to verify your answer. If someone else can confirm that your answer is correct, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands and steps as specified in https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html. Following those steps resolved my issue.